# How to validate non authenticated users from a mobile app on a server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, access-token, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

**My goal** : Have a mobile app that does not require users to ever sign in. Have these unauthenticated users hit my server.

**What I have** : My server is using the AWS API Gateway / AWS Lambda setup. The custom authorizer I used for AWS API Gateway was designed using this [example](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/blogs/compute/introducing-custom-authorizers-in-amazon-api-gateway/). I Also pasted the code from this example below **(A)**.

**My Question** : From the code block below (A), I get the impression I should use JWT. **How** can I use JWT to validate unauthenticated users when these tokens expire? If JWT is not the best thing to use, what would be?

Thanks!

**(A)**

```
var nJwt = require('njwt');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var signingKey = "CiCnRmG+t+ BASE 64 ENCODED ENCRYPTED SIGNING KEY Mk=";

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
   console.log('Client token: ' + event.authorizationToken);
   console.log('Method ARN: ' + event.methodArn);
   var kms = new AWS.KMS();

  var decryptionParams = {
     CiphertextBlob : new Buffer(signingKey, 'base64')
  }

  kms.decrypt(decryptionParams, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack);
    context.fail("Unable to load encryption key");
  } else {
    key = data.Plaintext;

  try {
    verifiedJwt = nJwt.verify(event.authorizationToken, key);
    console.log(verifiedJwt);

    // parse the ARN from the incoming event
    var apiOptions = {};
    var tmp = event.methodArn.split(':');
    var apiGatewayArnTmp = tmp[5].split('/');
    var awsAccountId = tmp[4];
    apiOptions.region = tmp[3];
    apiOptions.restApiId = apiGatewayArnTmp[0];
    apiOptions.stage = apiGatewayArnTmp[1];

    policy = new AuthPolicy(verifiedJwt.body.sub, awsAccountId, apiOptions);

    if (verifiedJwt.body.scope.indexOf("admins") > -1) {
       policy.allowAllMethods();
    } else {
      policy.allowMethod(AuthPolicy.HttpVerb.GET, "*");
      policy.allowMethod(AuthPolicy.HttpVerb.POST, "/users/" + verifiedJwt.body.sub);
    }

    context.succeed(policy.build());

  } catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex, ex.stack);
    context.fail("Unauthorized");
  }
}
});
};
```

Comment: If your users are unauthenticated, how do you expect them to receive a JWT?

Comment: Sorry I am still very new to web security. If Tokens are not the answer, is there another security measure I could utilize so I don't allow just anyone to hit my server?

Answer (score 0):

> My Question : From the code block below (A), I get the impression I
>   should use JWT. How can I use JWT to validate unauthenticated users
>   when these tokens expire? If JWT is not the best thing to use, what
>   would be?

Why do you need any validation at all? If you want to allow unauthenticated access to your API you should just do that and save yourself some effort.

**Update**

If you want to restrict access **and** not require a user to login, you may want to consider simply using [Cognito Identity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-identity.html). It supports unauthenticated identities and migration to authenticated access either via Cognito Your User Pools or another federated provider. It is worth noting that if you go this route, you will want to secure/obscure your identity pool id properly within your app to minimize the chance of it being extracted.

Using Cognito Identity, you would be able to get AWS credentials to sign the requests to your API using standard Signature version 4 and avoid the cost and overhead of managing a custom authorizer.

Comment: I want to protect my end point to not allow anyone to hit it. I have noticed plenty of Apps offer this, such as Hotel Tonight, and I assume that they must have security in place? If tokens aren't the answer, i'm looking for guidance to what this may be.

Comment: Thank you! this was helpful info.